# EF POCO table splitting: both entities load

Tags: .net, entity-framework, poco

Sorry, but I'm mystified by table splitting!

I have Product and ProductDetail entities, mapped to table Product.

When I load the Products collection, the ProductDetails are loaded too.

Could someone possibly explain how I can prevent ProductDetails being loaded until I really want them? Thanks!

```
        using (var ctx = new Context(cs))
        {
            var pc = ctx.Products.Local.Count();
            var pdc = ctx.ProductDetails.Local.Count();
            Assert.IsTrue(pc == 0);
            Assert.IsTrue(pdc == 0);

            ctx.Products.Load();

            pc = ctx.Products.Local.Count();
            pdc = ctx.ProductDetails.Local.Count();
            Assert.IsTrue(pc >= 10); //OK so far
            Assert.IsTrue(pdc == 0); //no, they are all there

        }
```

My context class and entities:

```
public class Context:DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public Context():base()
    {            
    }

    public Context(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductDetail> ProductDetails { get; set; }

}

[Table("Product")]
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("Product")]    
public class ProductDetail:Product
{
    //[Key]
    //public virtual int ProductId { get; set; }
    //public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you have `ProductDetail` inheriting from `Product`, which technically makes this a [Table-per-Hierarchy mapping](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx) rather than simple table splitting.  That means that, whenever you load all `Products`, you're necessarily loading all `ProductDetails` too.  The EF knows how to distinguish between the two, so as each entity is loaded, the Framework sorts it into the proper `DbSet` within your context -- they all get added to the `Products` set, but some also get added to `ProductDetails` set as well.

Fortunately, the solution is fairly simple: just make `ProductDetail` a separate class, not derived from `Product`.  Then you'll get the table spliting you're looking for:

```
[Table("Product")]
public class Product
{
  [Key]
  public int ProductId { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ProductDetail Details { get; set; }
}

[Table("Product")]
public class ProductDetail
{
  [Key]
  public int ProductId { get; set; }

  public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

You'll also need to use the Fluent API to set up the relationship in your context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

  modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
              .HasRequired(p => p.Details)
              .WithRequiredPrincipal();
}
```

Then you can just load a `Product` and access the description with `myProduct.Details.Description` (you probably won't need to access `ctx.ProductDetails` manually very much, if at all, with this setup).

Note that you'll have to have lazy loading enabled, or explicitly include the details in all the queries you want it with `ctx.Products.Include(p => p.Details)`, in order for this to work.

Hope this helps!  The distinctions between different types of table mappings can be pretty subtle sometimes.

Comment: Thank you! That explanation was concise, helpful and bang on. Just one more question... how do you get to learn this stuff? 8-)

Comment: Just by wondering why stuff didn't work and asking people who have been down that road before...it's the circle of life!